# Apache Airflow - Connection issue to MS SQL Server using pymssql + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, airflow, pymssql

I am facing a problem to connect to an **Azure MS SQL Server 2014** database in **Apache Airflow 1.10.1** using **pymssql**.
I want to use the **MsSqlHook** class provided by Airflow, for the convenience to create my connection in the Airflow UI, and then create a context manager for my connection using **SqlAlchemy**:

```
@contextmanager
def mssql_session(dt_conn_id):
    sqla_engine = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id=dt_conn_id).get_sqlalchemy_engine()
    session = sessionmaker(bind=sqla_engine)()
    try:
        yield session
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        session.commit()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

But when I do that, I have this error when I run a request :

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002',
>   '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no
>   default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

It seems come from *pyodbc* whereas I want to use *pymssql* (and in *MsSqlHook*, the method *get_conn* uses *pymssql* !)

I searched in the source code of Airflow the cause.
I noticed that the method *get_uri* from the class *DbApiHook* (from which is inherited *MsSqlHook*) builds the connection string passed to *SqlAlchemy* like this:

> '{conn.conn_type}://{login}{host}/{conn.schema}'

But *conn.conn_type* is simply equal to '*mssql*' whereas we need to specify the DBAPI as described here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server
(for example : '**mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname**')

So, by default, I think it uses *pyodbc*.
But how can I set properly the *conn_type* of the connection to '*mssql+pymssql*' instead of '*mssql*' ?
In the Airflow IU, you can simply select SQL server in a dropdown list, but not set as you want :

[image: Airflow UI choose connection type]

To work around the issue, I overload the *get_uri* method from *DbApiHook* in a new class I created inherited from *MsSqlHook*, and in which I build my own connection string, but it's not clean at all...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

You're right. There's no easy, straightforward way to get Airflow to do what you want. Personally I would build the sqlalchemy engine inside of your context manager, something like `create_engine(hook.get_uri().replace("://", "+pymssql://"))` -- then I would toss the code somewhere reusable.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's better like that. I keep the question open if someone has a solution with configuration only.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a connection by passing it as an environment variable to Airflow. See [the docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/manage-connections.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables). The value of the variable is the database URL in the format SqlAlchemy accepts.

The name of the env var follows the pattern `AIRFLOW_CONN_` to which you append the connection ID. For example `AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MSSQL`, in this case, the `conn_id` would be `'my_mssql'`.