# Running Apache Airflow with Azure SQL server as backend DB

Tags: odbc, azure-sql-database, python-3.6, airflow, pymssql

I'm trying to run airflow with Azure SQL database as backend using mssql+pyodbc connection string(all relevant drivers have been installed).

while airflow is able to connect to DB and create tables, i.e, *airflow initdb* runs successfully, I'm facing issues while running airflow scheduler, as a result, the tasks triggered are always in "running" state.

This is the error I get while running airflow scheduler:

```
*sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
     [SQL: SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id
    FROM dag
    WHERE dag.is_paused IS 1 AND dag.dag_id IN (?)]
    [parameters: ('example_http_operator',)]*
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

I'm using `apache-airflow==1.10.11`.
If you were able to run airflow + azure SQL DB with any configuration please feel free to jump in.

Comment: airflow doesn't officially support mssql / azure as backend db. It's only tested against MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is @Elad comment still true?  The 2.2.0 release notes (end of 2021) still call MSSQL experimental.  My DBAs only support MSSQL, would help me a ton.

Comment: Airflow 2.2 does not support mssql. Future versions will support it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a document and talk the configuration about run airflow + azure SQL DB. Maybe it's helpful for you.

Ref: [Setting up Airflow on Azure & connecting to MS SQL Server](https://medium.com/analytics-and-data/setting-up-airflow-on-azure-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-8c06784a7e2b)

This post also give some configurations about it: [Apache Airflow - Connection issue to MS SQL Server using pymssql + SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616630/apache-airflow-connection-issue-to-ms-sql-server-using-pymssql-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL as backend DB, there is workaround in [Airflow#10713](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10713). I using `apache-airflow==1.10.15` and solved same error as yours.

The command suggested is attached, but I use `vi` update instead of run `sed` command.

```
RUN sed -i 's/import copy/import copy,sqlalchemy/g' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py \ && sed -i 's/DagModel.is_paused.is_(True)/DagModel.is_paused == sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true()/g' /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py
```