# How can I add new "Conn Types" to Airflow 2.0?

Tags: python, connection, airflow

I'm learning Apache Airflow 2.0 and I was creating a new "Connection" but in "Conn Type" there are just a few options, for example I want to add a MySQL connection but there isn't that option. In this post ([Apache Airflow - Connection issue to MS SQL Server using pymssql + SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616630/apache-airflow-connection-issue-to-ms-sql-server-using-pymssql-sqlalchemy)) you can see they have a lot of conn types and I want to know how to create or add new types, right now I need MySQL type but it is probable I need more in the future (like AWS, GCP, etc). I had to create a connection from the CLI but if I edit it from the UI, the conn type is lost so it's a problem...

So they have all those options in conn type:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7XT.png)

And I have just these options:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOOfg.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use MySQL Provider to do that either via:

```
pip install -U 'apache-airflow[mysql]'
```

or

```
pip install -U apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow-providers/index.html#extending-airflow-connections-and-extra-links-via-providers

From Airflow 2.0.0, the connection type would only be show for the Providers that are already installed.